# If $R$ is a finite boolean then $R \cong \mathbb{Z_2} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z_2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This question wants me to use a previous result, that if $e$ is a central idempotent in $R$ then $R \cong Re \oplus R(1-e)$. I was thinking about maybe some sort of induction would help here but I can't see exactly how I am going to get to the result I want.

I would like to know how to do the problem this way, because this is the way the book recommends. However, I also have heard that this problem can be done another way, by realizing that $R$ is a vector space over $Z_2$ and there has a finite basis, and i am under the impression that the result is not far away knowing this, but I can't quite connect the dots.

If somebody could guide me along these two different routes of solving this problem I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Also consider looking at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305556/boolean-ring-representation-as-direct-product or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1398323/29335

Comment: And to argue along the lines you want: Just note that if $e\notin\{0,1\}$, $Re$ and $R(1-e)$ are also boolean rings with strictly smaller cardinality than $R$, with identities $e$ and $1-e$ respectively.  You can decompose such a ring repeatedly until literally the thing you have is $\{0,1\}$, and no further decomposition can occur.  Since $R$ is finite, you can clearly do this for all the pieces of $R$, so you eventually wind up with $\prod F_2$ for some finite number of copies of $F_2$

Comment: Or perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2428051/29335 is an even better duplicate. Please, please, please look for duplicates before you post.  In this case searching "finite boolean" seemed to suffice.

Comment: @rschwieb You say in your second comment that you can decompose such a ring repeatedly. Forgive me if I'm missing something, but can you explain exactly how you do that? Thank you.

Comment: @Emily that was explained in the sentence before the one you are quoting, and the first sentence of the post .  $R=eR\oplus (1-e)R$

Comment: @rschwieb Apologies, I'm still not seeing what to do. If using your sentence before, surely you just end up going in a circle over and over, surely it doesn't reduce down?

Comment: @Emily Do you understand that $|eR|$ and $|(1-e)R|$ are strictly smaller than $|R|$ when $e$ is nontrivial?

Comment: @rschwieb I should, but I'm not confident. Would you mind explaining please?

Comment: I've also realised I'm working with $R \cong Re \otimes R(1-e)$ rather than $R \cong Re \oplus R(1-e)$ in the question.

Comment: @Emily The elements of the decomposition $eR\oplus(1-e)R$ are in one to one correspondence with the Cartesian product $eR\times (1-e)R$, and it is elementary to prove for finite sets $|A\times B|=|A||B|$.  I can’t make it any more elementary. You’ll actually have to engage your mind from here on.

Comment: @Emily The ring is commutative so $eR=Re$ and it makes no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105586/discussion-between-emily-and-rschwieb).

Answer (score 1):

1. A boolean ring is always commutative:
   $$a+b=(a+b)^2 =a^2 +b^2 + ab + ba = a+b+ab+ba$$
   Hence $ab+ba=0$. Applying the same with $a=b=x$ yields $x+x=0$, so $x=-x$ for all $x$, and we have $ba=-ab=ab$.
   And, by definition, also every element is idempotent, so we can arbitrarily pick a nontrivial element $e$, until there is such, and use induction and the previously proved claim.
2. By the above result ($x+x=0$), we indeed get a $\Bbb Z_2$ vector space structure in $R$, and since it's finite, it has a finite basis. All you have to verify is that multiplication of $R$ coincides with the coordinatewise multiplication once a basis is fixed.